# How to unrate multiple album ratings at the same time?

Tags: itunes, automation, album, ratings

I'm using iTunes 12.2.1.16 and today I realized that there is something called 'album rating'. This messes up my ordering according to the track rating. Suddenly there are songs appearing with hollow stars that I never rated.

I found out that this is the automatic album rating from iTunes. So far so bad. I also managed to disable it for one album.

But how can I unrate my entire library? In the album view I can select multiple albums, but not set the album rating...

iTunes driving me crazy again...

It's about deleting the album rating, not the track rating.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking to do the same thing the OP requested here. This was my solution:

Open the Music app (formerly iTunes in macOS 10.14 and earlier) and do one of the following:

- create a new smart playlist with the criteria that album rating does not equal zero stars (the star to the left of the first star) then open up that smart playlist and select all the songs therein
- sort tracks by album rating and select all the songs that have a non-zero album rating.

Next, open up `Script Editor.app` and paste in the following script:

```
tell application "Music"
    repeat with theSong in selection
        set album rating of theSong to 0
    end repeat
end tell
```

You may need to run it more than once as it may fail as the selection changes while songs are being removed from the smart playlist. After a successful execution, all manual album ratings will be removed. Some albums may still have grayed out ratings: these are from the song ratings themselves and aren't actually album ratings.

Comment: This worked brilliantly! They didn't disappear from the Smart Playlist, but the tracks aren't showing up in other playlists anymore (where they should not be).

Answer (score 1):

I was also having trouble with getting rid of the normal Rating hollow stars, as opposed to the Album Rating stars (which I didn't even know they existed). What finally worked for me was to show the Album Rating as an option on the column, then manually delete them off the ones that were showing on the Rating column as hollow stars, and it worked!, I just picked any rated song from that given album and it took away all of them in that album. Hopefully this makes some sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a defect in iTunes which is causing some albums to attain USER ratings (black stars) instead of ESTIMATED ratings (grey stars). When this happens, it causes the album's individual tracks to have ESTIMATED ratings (grey stars), which messes up your smart playlists.

Comment: Yes. That is definitely still happening. I thought I had my ratings-base playlists fixed (by removing all album ratings) and then I synced with my old Nano and they all came back. It's not the end of the world... but really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you dismiss the field you will be happy.  Also rate the a song's album rating to just before the first star (NO stars).

Select “Grid View”

Press “Apple key ⌘ + A” to select all – CTRL+A if you’re using a PC
Right click and select “Album Rating > None”

By right clicking on the column header line you can add or delete field columns.

[image]

Comment: No, that won't help, because the hollow stars are also appearing in the normal rating column...

Comment: Try the edited answer, I fixed it but it was a while ago, bad memory!! v 12 is a new view, may be hard to selet grid view in 12.

Comment: If you show me a screenshot with all albums selected and right-clicking and "album rating -> none" then I believe you :D  But I only see the rating for the tracks (album rating is visible as header). But it seems that they have fixed the problem that album ratings are interrupting the sorted list by track rating?

Comment: I was trying to illustrate how you can dismiss the album rating column entirely, That shot is of the column headers being selected. I never see an 'Album Rating' column anywhere.

Comment: If you right click in the column header line you can bring up that window to choose which columns are used and or displayed. That also is showing all of my 6000+ albums. By unchoosing the Album Rating column it is gone as shown.

Answer (score 0):

DougScripts has an [AppleScript](https://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=albumratingreset) that will do this for you for selected songs, playlists, or your entire library.

Answer (score -1):

Albums are rated on an average of the Track ratings making them up.

As far as I can see, you cannot eliminate one without the other, though you could just hide the column & see if it works for you.

To clear all ratings... ***both Song & Album***
You cannot undo this, so don't try it just to see...

Go to My Music.
Sort on the right by Songs.
Right click the header if 'Rating' is not one of the headers & add it.
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>  to select all
Right-click one song & select rating/None

Done.

All ratings are cleared.

Comment: Your advice will delete all track ratings. But I want to delete all album ratings.

Comment: as I said - "Albums are rated on an average of the Track ratings making them up." Can't get rid of one without the other

Comment: Actually, you can rate the album or the individual tracks. If you rated the individual tracks, sometimes that would give an average rating to the album, but not always. This rating will be greyed out. If you rated the album instead, that would give all unrated songs the same rating as the album, but hollowed or greyed out, as the OP said. I can't find where to disable or modify the rating other than activating the Album Rating column.

Comment: -1 - advising to wipe out track ratings is just bad.  (regardless of the relationship.  you could cause unsuspecting users to lose data.)  (and yes, you CAN ~~remove album ratings - solid star ratings fairly easily, hollow star seems to have to be done with applescript)

Comment: @keen Then rather than just downvote, why not provide an answer yourself? No-one will find it down here in comments.